Lua: await the completion of multiple coroutines
In JavaScript, there's
const a, b = await Promise.all([task1(), task2()])

In Python, there's
a, b = await asyncio.gather(task1(), task2())

Is there Lua's equivalent of the above?
local task1 = coroutine.create(...)
local task2 = coroutine.create(...)
local a, b = coroutine.resume_all(task1, task2) -- No such method

-- All the coroutines have run to completion or errored.
assert(coroutine.status(task1) == 'dead')
assert(coroutine.status(task2) == 'dead')


I don't know about python but javascript doesn't run them in parallel. For lua, a function which resumes the coroutine until all are finished has the same effect.

Rephrased to avoid making an impression that the question is about genuinely parallel programming/

Python and JavaScript have actual "event loops", implemented for example via select, epoll or similar syscalls (no code is running in parallel on the CPU, however). Lua does not have this. As tkausl said, you can implement something similar yourself, by using nonblocking functions in your coroutines and resuming (polling) them until they have run to completion. A good example of this is given in the PIL.

I'll just quote Programming in Lua:

A coroutine is similar to a thread (in the sense of multithreading): a
line of execution, with its own stack, its own local variables, and
its own instruction pointer; but sharing global variables and mostly
anything else with other coroutines. The main difference between
threads and coroutines is that, conceptually (or literally, in a
multiprocessor machine), a program with threads runs several threads
concurrently. Coroutines, on the other hand, are collaborative: A
program with coroutines is, at any given time, running only one of its
coroutines and this running coroutine only suspends its execution when
it explicitly requests to be suspended.

Hence there is no function to run several coroutines concurrently.
Lua runs in a single thread, hence nothing is being executed in parallel. You can only isolate tasks and schedule them. For example if one coroutine has nothing to do at the moment, you can hand over control to another coroutine.
You'll find some libraries to work around this though.
